# How do I ensure proper encoding in an R script running in a Docker container that queries data from a database on an SQL server?

Tags: r, sql-server, postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I would like to run a daily scheduled R Script (within a Docker Container) which establishes two connections. One connection to a Databank on a remote MS SQL Server, from which data is retrieved. Another connection to a Postgres database - which is located on the server on which the script/Container is also running - to which data is written.

So the Script is basically following the order:

(1)

```
con_sql = DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  Driver = Sys.getenv("MSSQL_DRIVER"),
  Server = Sys.getenv("MSSQL_SERVER"),
  Database = Sys.getenv("MSSQL_DATABASE"),
  UID = Sys.getenv("MSSQL_USER"),
  PWD = Sys.getenv("MSSQL_PASSWORD"),
  Port = Sys.getenv("MSSQL_PORT"),
  encoding = "latin-1")
```

(2)

```
con_postgres = DBI::dbConnect(
  drv = RPostgres::Postgres(),
  dbname = Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_DATABASE"),
  host = Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_HOST"),
  port = Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_PORT"),
  user = Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_USER"),
  password = Sys.getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"))
```

(3)

```
tbl(con_sql, "sales") %>%
  filter(
    datum>="2023-01-01" &
    belegart=="Auftragsbestätigung") %>%
  select(
    datum, sales, kunde, artikel) %>%  
  collect() %>%

  DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = con_postgres, name = "sales_2023", value = ., row.names = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:latest

#update all packages
RUN apt-get update

#upgrade
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

#install additional packages
RUN apt install gpg-agent -y unixodbc build-essential curl libssl1.1 libssl-dev gnupg2 software-properties-common dirmngr apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates

#get msodbcsql17 and install it
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc unixodbc-dev mssql-tools

RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev postgresql-client
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev

RUN apt-get -y install locales
RUN apt update && apt install -y locales \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && localedef -i de_DE -f ISO-8859-1 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias de_DE.ISO-8859-1
ENV LANG de_DE.ISO-8859-1
ENV LC_ALL de_DE.ISO-8859-1

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('DBI')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('RPostgres')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('odbc')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('lubridate')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('dplyr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('dbplyr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('tidyr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('purrr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('tibble')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('stringr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('readr')"

COPY / /

# Run the command on container startup
CMD Rscript /sql.R
```

The problem is that the final table in the Postgres database is empty, which is due to the fact that Belegart 'Auftragbestätigung' cannot be filtered due to the fact that it contains an 'ä'. Other Belegarten like 'Rechnung' can be filtered without problems. What can I do? I don't know if it's a problem with my R script - the connection - or the Dockerfile.

Comment: So how would you handle any other non-ASCII character in an R script? Have you tried `"Auftragsbest\u00e4tigung"` yet?

Comment: There were not any other non-ASCII characters to handle yet :-) Your suggestion gives me the error 'Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
  error in evaluating the argument 'value' in selecting a method for function 'dbWriteTable': unsupported conversion from '' to 'latin-1'''